# Prove that two functions are differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble with two parts of a problem that I have found in a book on multivariate calculus. Both of the parts that I'm having trouble with involve determining whether or not a given bivariate function is differentiable at $(0,0)$.  $f_{i}(0,0) = 0$ for both functions. Below are the definitions of the two functions when $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$.
\begin{equation}
f_{1}(x,y) = xy \frac{x^{2} - y^{2}}{x^{2} + y^{2}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
f_{2}(x,y) = xy \ln(x^{2} + y^{2})
\end{equation}
Can someone show me a means of showing whether or not $f_{1}$ or $f_{2}$ are differentiable.

Comment: Well, what's the limit definition of a derivative at a given point? Can you write that down? Then just see if that limit exists.

Comment: As Don Thousand asked, where are you in terms of the definition at this time?  If you need to use the "$\epsilon-delta$" definition of the derivative that's going to be very hard.  If you can use things like the "product rule", "quotient rule", etc. it is fairly straight forward.  If you can use the fact that a composition of differentiable functions is differentiable (as long as the denominator is not 0) it very easy. Which do you need?

Comment: @user247327: At the point $(0,0)$ (which is what the question was about), it's not that easy! You'll need to use the definition of differentiability somehow, or maybe the theorem that functions of class $C^1$ are differentiable (but then you still need to compute the first partials at the origin from the definition).

Comment: I think a proof that uses the fact that compositions of differentiable functions are differentiable would suffice.